# problem with gfortran compilation on MAC OS Catalina - Error ld: unexpected token: !tapi-tbd-v3 file

Tags: macos, gcc, compiler-errors, macos-catalina

I am trying to compile a .f90 program with gfortan on MAC OS Catalina and I am getting the following error:

```
Error ld: unexpected token: !tapi-tbd-v3 file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd' for architecture x86_64
```

the gfortan version installed and configured as following:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0_1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin19/9.3.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19
Configured with: ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin19 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0_1 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0_1/lib/gcc/9 --disable-nls --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran --program-suffix=-9 --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp --with-mpfr=/usr/local/opt/mpfr --with-mpc=/usr/local/opt/libmpc --with-isl=/usr/local/opt/isl --with-system-zlib --with-pkgversion='Homebrew GCC 9.3.0_1' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues --disable-multilib --with-native-system-header-dir=/usr/include --with-sysroot=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk SED=/usr/bin/sed
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.3.0 (Homebrew GCC 9.3.0_1)
```

How I could fix that?